# How can i open a word file into my app which is stored in my google drive

Tags: java, android, xml, pdf, ms-word

I want to open a word or pdf file in my code that file must be stored on any internet resource because when I will change in pdf file or word file it will change it in all user's app.
I try to find many ways to resolve it but couldn't find any thing.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open

You can integrate the google drive API. Please go through the link you will find details about how to integrate it into your system.

Comment: But is there any method to load a word or pdf file with the same format in android program...?